# What happened to Underminer in the Incredibles 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, incredibles-2

In the Incredibles 2, at the beginning of the film, the Incredibles get in trouble by trying to stop the Super villain Underminer. They fail to catch him, and he runs away free. Throughout the movie, there is no indication that they ever catch him. Did he get caught, or did he get away?

Answer (score 6):

If you wait until the very end of the credits, you can see his 'escape drill' riding away underground. At least in the time frame contemplated by this movie, he escapes.